# Can't implement discount on specific product on Shopify Liquid

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid, shopify-api

I am trying to manually create a hard-coded upsell banner in the cart in Shopify using Liquid and Javascript, where the banner will advertise product X on a 20% discount they add it using the banner. I am trying to do this without creating a 'discounted' variant of the product.

This is the ajax call to add the product to cart if the user clicks on "Add" in the upsell banner. I differentiate this product from ones with the same variant in the cart by adding the property "isUpsellProduct".

```
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/cart/add.js',
      data: {
        id: variantId,
        quantity: quantity,
        properties: {
          isUpsellProduct: true,
        },
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (product) {
        //Sucess Logic
      },
```

Now let's say we have product X in cart already from adding it through the product page, and the product being used in the Upsell is product X also, I want to make the upsell product have a 20% on it's price, and only the upsell product, not the other product.

I know that I can't manipulate prices directly using Shopify APIs or even Shopify Functions.
If I create a discount code that applies, it will apply to the whole order or to the product, but if I apply it based on product, it will be applied on both product X, the upsell one and the none-upsell one, which would force me to create a variant, and I don't want to create a variant.

Any ideas how can I implement this? I know Shopify Functions can apply discounts conditionally, from what I've look at in the docs this use case doesn't apply, is this specific use case doable via Shopify Functions discount API? Or is there any workaround for this?

Comment: liquid has been deprecated and will be removed August 13, 2024